# Single Sign-on for Intranet WordPress using OpenID (or OAuth), IIS, Integrated Windows Authentication, Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, iis, wordpress, ntlm, openid

Is it possible to have single sign-on for intranet WordPress sites by using OpenID (or OAuth), IIS, Integrated Windows Authentication, Active Directory?

I'd like to have Active Directory users automatically log in to non-IIS (LAMP) intranet sites like WordPress. We have intranet sites where users log in automatically using integrated NTLM. Could we host an OpenID provider on an IIS site where users log in automatically using their domain credentials?

Answer (score 1):

I would try the [WordPress Active Directory Plug In](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/active-directory-authentication/).

I'm getting ready to use this on a project, and I think that it looks promising.